# Is there a single Linux commandline tool that displays network connections AND processes

Tags: networking, command-line-interface

Bascially, I'm looking for a combination of iftop and nethogs in a single tool.

iftop shows information on the network layer: source/destination target and ports, throughput and all that in a nice ncurses interface.

nethogs shows which users and PIDs/program names are using how much throughput.

Both tools display valuable information, but I find the need to have both installed on all machines and having to switch back and forth cumbersome.

Is there a tool that does both, with a command-line interface?